# SocketCluster Client -- TypeError: WebSocket is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socketcluster

I am new to javascript and am trying to develop a react.js application including communication over socketcluster framework. The client should not run in the browser but in a separate javascript file in the background.

To realize this, I have installed the necessary modules for server (https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster) and client (https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client).

I followed the instructions and the communication between server and client (javascript code embedded in html, run in browser) worked. But when I try to run the client in a seperate javascript (gbab-client.js) file with "node gbam-client.js", it doesn't.
I would be very grateful for your help!

Content of gbab-client.js:

```
const socketClusterClient = require('socketcluster-client/socketcluster');

const options = {
    port: 2222
};

// Initiate the connection to the server
const socket = socketClusterClient.connect(options);
console.log('Connecting...');

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('CONNECTED');
});

// Listen to an event called 'rand' from the server
socket.on('rand', function (num) {
    console.log('RANDOM: ' + num);
});
```

Error Message:

```
$ node gbam-client.js


C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:1306
    return new WebSocket(uri, null, options);
           ^

TypeError: WebSocket is not a constructor
    at createWebSocket (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:1306:12)
    at new SCTransport (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:1337:18)
    at SCClientSocket.connect.SCClientSocket.open (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:558:22)
    at new SCClientSocket (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:433:10)
    at Object.create (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js:198:31)
    at Object.module.exports.create (C:\...\node_modules\socketcluster-client\socketcluster.js: 14:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\gbam-client.js:12:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution. The destination of require wasn't right.

This is the corrected code (gbam-client.js):

```
const socketClusterClient = require('socketcluster-client');

const options = {
    hostname:'localhost',
    port: 2222
};

...
```

Comment: For testing I wrote a websocket server and client. It works fine. They can communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ws (WebSocket library) version is not compatible with socketcluster, try to update it [WS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

Comment: I updated all my modules but it dosn't work... (Two modules didn't updated: express and serve-static)